# Numpy efficient matrix self-multiplication (gram matrix)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I want to multiply `B = A @ A.T` in numpy. Obviously, the answer would be a symmetric matrix (i.e. `B[i, j] == B[j, i]`).

However, it is not clear to me how to leverage this easily to cut the computation time down in half (by only computing the lower triangle of `B` and then using that to get the upper triangle for free).

Is there a way to perform this optimally?

Comment: Search the BLAS or other optimized libraries for such a function, and link it to your code with `cython` or other such tool.  It's too specialized for existing `numpy` functions.

Comment: @hpaulj. But not for scipy perhaps?

Comment: Actually, numpy does it for you, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43454451/7207392) post.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, how'd you find that!   To think I commented on the topic, and didn't remember :(  Memory must be going.  `dot` is detecting the special case and using a different `BLAS` call.

Comment: @hpaulj _To think I commented on the topic, and didn't remember_ yeah, memory is a funny thing. I, actually did remember because I found it so fascinating at the time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As noted in @PaulPanzer's link, `dot` can detect this case.  Here's the timing proof:

```
In [355]: A = np.random.rand(1000,1000)
In [356]: timeit A.dot(A.T)
57.4 ms ± 960 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [357]: B = A.T.copy()
In [358]: timeit A.dot(B)
98.6 ms ± 805 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

[Numpy dot too clever about symmetric multiplications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453707/numpy-dot-too-clever-about-symmetric-multiplications/43454451#43454451)

Comment: With `A = np.random.rand(1000,3); B = A.T.copy()`.I get : `%timeit A.dot(B) : 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 ms per loop` and `%timeit A.dot(A.T) : 100 loops, best of 3: 2.2 ms per loop`. Can you reproduce? If so, do you know why transpose version is slower with such a case of small no. of cols? Is `syrk` slower with those?

Answer (score 2):

You can always use [sklearns's pairwise_distances](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html)

Usage:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
gram = pairwise_distance(x, metric=metric)
```

Where `metric` is a callable or a string defining one of their implemented metrics (full list in the link above)

---

But, I wrote this for myself a while back so I can share what I did:

```
import numpy as np

def computeGram(elements, dist):
    n    = len(elements)
    gram = np.zeros([n, n])
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i + 1):
            gram[i, j] = dist(elements[i], elements[j])

    upTriIdxs       = np.triu_indices(n)
    gram[upTriIdxs] = gram.T[upTriIdxs]

    return gram
```

Where `dist` is a callable, in your case `np.inner`

Comment: In my sample tests these calculations are 20x slower than `x.dot(x)`.

Comment: @hpaulj yeah it's a bit of an overkill for `dot()`, I wrote this to handle  more complicated metrics