# Numpy Performance - Outer Product of a vector with its transpose

Tags: python, numpy, vector, transpose

It is my understanding that the Outer Product of a vector with its transpose is symmetric in value.

Does Numpy take this into account to only do the multiplications for the upper triangle part of the output or does it calculate the whole output matrix (even though it is symmetric and time + memory could go to waste?)

Comment: What do you call outer product? To my knowledge, the outer product of two vectors is not symmetric.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question. I meant the outer product of a vector with its own transpose: A*A.T

Comment: What's a `vector`?  That's not formally defined in numpy, Give an example of the calc.

Comment: Do some time tests. A `dot` may detect a transpose, say with a (n,1) and (1,n)

Comment: @hpaulj according to this link the dot product already does this but not sure about the outer product: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453707/numpy-dot-too-clever-about-symmetric-multiplications

Comment: @hpaulj a vector is just a 1 dimensional array. A = Mx1 array so AxA.T = MxM matrix.

Comment: (m,) is 1d. (m,1) is 2d.  which outer `x.T*x` or `outer(x,x)`.  Does that link give any hints as how `dot` detects this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exploring some alternatives:

```
In [162]: x=np.arange(100)
In [163]: np.outer(x,x)
Out[163]: 
array([[   0,    0,    0, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    1,    2, ...,   97,   98,   99],
       [   0,    2,    4, ...,  194,  196,  198],
       ...,
       [   0,   97,  194, ..., 9409, 9506, 9603],
       [   0,   98,  196, ..., 9506, 9604, 9702],
       [   0,   99,  198, ..., 9603, 9702, 9801]])
In [164]: x1=x[:,None]
In [165]: x1*x1.T
Out[165]: 
array([[   0,    0,    0, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    1,    2, ...,   97,   98,   99],
       [   0,    2,    4, ...,  194,  196,  198],
       ...,
       [   0,   97,  194, ..., 9409, 9506, 9603],
       [   0,   98,  196, ..., 9506, 9604, 9702],
       [   0,   99,  198, ..., 9603, 9702, 9801]])
In [166]: np.dot(x1,x1.T)
Out[166]: 
array([[   0,    0,    0, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    1,    2, ...,   97,   98,   99],
       [   0,    2,    4, ...,  194,  196,  198],
       ...,
       [   0,   97,  194, ..., 9409, 9506, 9603],
       [   0,   98,  196, ..., 9506, 9604, 9702],
       [   0,   99,  198, ..., 9603, 9702, 9801]])
```

Comparing their times:

```
In [167]: timeit np.outer(x,x)
40.8 µs ± 63.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [168]: timeit x1*x1.T
36.3 µs ± 22 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [169]: timeit np.dot(x1,x1.T)
60.7 µs ± 6.86 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Is `dot` using a transpose short cut?  I don't think so, or if it does, it doesn't help in this case.  I'm a little surprised that `dot` is slower.

```
In [170]: x2=x1.T
In [171]: timeit np.dot(x1,x2)
61.1 µs ± 30 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Another method

```
In [172]: timeit np.einsum('i,j',x,x)
28.3 µs ± 19.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

`einsum` with `x1` and `x2` has the same times.

Interesting that `matmul` does as well as `einsum` in this case (maybe `einsum` is delegating to `matmul`?)

```
In [178]: timeit x1@x2
27.3 µs ± 1.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [179]: timeit x1@x1.T
27.2 µs ± 14.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

[Numpy efficient matrix self-multiplication (gram matrix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50733148/numpy-efficient-matrix-self-multiplication-gram-matrix) demonstrates how `dot` can be save time by being clever (for a 1000x1000 array).

As discussed in the links, `dot` can detect when one argument is the transpose of the other (probably by checking the data buffer pointer and shape and strides), and can use a BLAS function optimized for symmetric calculations.  But I don't see evidence of `outer` doing that.  And its unlikely that broadcasted multiplication would take such a step.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed analysis... So far it seems that `matmul` and `einsum` are faster than the other alternatives... I wonder if they stay fast when we scale the data to millions of 32bit floats or not...

Comment: I found with numpy 1.26 that `x[:, None] @ x[None, :]` is slightly faster than `x[:, None] * x[None, :]`