# What is the fastest way to compute a sparse Gram matrix in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

A Gram matrix is a matrix of the structure `X @ X.T` which of course is symmetrical. When dealing with dense matrices, the `numpy.dot` product implementation is intelligent enough to recognize the self-multiplication to exploit the symmetry and thus speed up the computations (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50734430/1444073)). However, no such effect can be observed when using `scipy.sparse` matrices:

```
random.seed(0)
X = random.randn(5,50)
X[X < 1.5] = 0
X = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(X)
print(f'sparsity of X: {100 * (1 - X.count_nonzero() / prod(X.shape)):5.2f} %')
# sparsity of X: 92.00 %

%timeit X @ X.T
# 248 µs ± 10.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

X2 = X.copy()
%timeit X @ X2.T
# 251 µs ± 9.38 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

So I was wondering: What is the fastest way to compute a sparse Gram matrix in Python? Notably, it is sufficient to only compute the lower (or equivalently, the upper) triangle.

I've read multiple times, that using the [skyline format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyline_matrix) is very efficient for symmetrical matrices, however, scipy doesn't support the skyline format. Instead, people were pointing towards [pysparse](http://pysparse.sourceforge.net/) many times, but it seems that pysparse has been discontinued a long time ago and there is no support for Python 3. At least, my Anaconda rejects to install pysparse due to compatibility issues with Python 3.

Comment: Sparse matrix transposition in scipy produces a new matrix, so there is no way to exploit symmetry like in numpy, where transposition is only flags applied to a view

Comment: @talonmies Are you sure? `X_coo = X.tocoo(); X_coo.data is X_coo.T.data` is `True`

Comment: Positive. The transpose of CSR matrix is a CSC matrix -- https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/bf4e01b5862a8f20dd79f799ac2330f40cb93897/scipy/sparse/csr.py#L135 . And the resulting CSC matrix has its own indices which are not detectable as the same as the source CSR matrix.

Comment: The fastest way is `mkl_sparse_syrk` from Intel's mkl library, although it's a C function and calling it from python isn't trivial

Comment: Can you try storing X2 = (X.T).copy() and then compute X@X2? It seems to be a bit faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of the user CJR, I worked out a satisfying solution. In fact, I found [a library on GitHub](https://github.com/flatironinstitute/sparse_dot) which wraps the MKL routine `mkl_sparse_spmm` for Python. This routine is for fast multiplication of two sparse matrices. So all I had to do was to extend the library and provide a similar wrapper for `mkl_sparse_syrk`. And this is exactly [what I did](https://github.com/kostrykin/sparse_dot).

I still have to add some comments, afterwards I will submit a pull request to the original project.

However, here are the performance results, quite impressing:

```
random.seed(0)
X = random.randn(500, 5000)
X[X < 0.8] = 0
X = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(X)
print(f'X sparsity: {100 * (1 - X.count_nonzero() / prod(X.shape)):5.2f} %')
# X sparsity: 78.80 %

expected_result = (X @ X.T).toarray()
expected_result_triu = expected_result.copy()
expected_result_triu[tril_indices(expected_result.shape[0], k=-1)] = 0

mkl_result1 = sparse_dot_mkl.dot_product_mkl(X, X.T)
allclose(mkl_result1.toarray(), expected_result)
# True

mkl_result2 = sparse_dot_mkl.dot_product_transpose_mkl(X)
allclose(mkl_result2.toarray(), expected_result_triu)
# True

%timeit X @ X.T
# 197 ms ± 5.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit sparse_dot_mkl.dot_product_mkl(X, X.T)
# 70.6 ms ± 593 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit sparse_dot_mkl.dot_product_transpose_mkl(X)
# 34.2 ms ± 421 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Using the generic dot product from MKL instead of the dot product implementation from scipy yields a *speed-up of 279%*. Using the specialized product for Gram matrix computation yields a *speed-up of 576%*. This is huge.