# Speed up left matmul for scipy.sparse.csr_matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I need to perform the following matrix multiplication : `x * A[idx]` where `A` is a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`, and `idx` is a `np.array` index. I can't change it to `csc_matrix` because of the indexing.
It seems to be 50x slower than the right matrix multiplication `A[idx] * x`, and only slightly faster than the left matrix multiplication  (over the full index) `u * A`, even when `len(idx) << A.shape[0]`. How can I speed this up?

Comment: For what it's worth `A[idx]` is implemented as a matmul using a sparse extractor matrix constructed from `idx`.

Comment: Based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61867890/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-compute-a-sparse-gram-matrix-in-python) I would recommend using MKL with the [sparse_dot_mkl](https://pypi.org/project/sparse-dot-mkl/) wrapper.

Comment: Linking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46924092/how-to-parallelize-this-python-for-loop-when-using-numba), which has a nice parallel solution to a similar question: M.dot(v).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I didn't find a solution elsewhere, here's what I ended up doing.

Using `numba`, I wrote:

```
@njit(nogil=True)
def fast_csr_vm(x, data, indptr, indices, d, idx):
    """
    Returns the vector matrix product x * M[idx]. M is described
    in the csr format.
    Returns x * M[idx]
    x: 1-d iterable
    data: data field of a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix
    indptr: indptr field of a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix
    indices: indices field of a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix
    d: output dimension
    idx: 1-d iterable: index of the sparse.csr_matrix
    """
    res = np.zeros(d)
    assert x.shape[0] == len(idx)
    for k, i in np.ndenumerate(idx):
        for j in range(indptr[i], indptr[i+1]):
            j_idx = indices[j]
            res[j_idx] += x[k] * data[j]
    return res
```

Comment: Especially since you aren't returning a sparse matrix, direct action on the matrix attributes makes a lot of sense